# Angular Directive to replace html not working on iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this piece of code:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular
    .module("Default")
    .directive(
      "numberToTime",
      ["$rootScope", "$compile", "$log",
      function($rootScope, $compile, $log) {
        return {
          "restrict": "A",
          "transclude": true,
          "replace": true,
          "scope": {
            "time": "="
          },
          "link": function(scope, ele, attrs) {

            /**
             * Function to add one serie of string to another untill complete
             * certain length
             *
             */
            var _lpad = function(str, padString, length) {
              while (str.length < length) {
                str = padString + str;
              }
              return str;
            };

            /**
             * Function to turn a number into time format
             */
            var _2time = function(s, hideDays, hideSeconds) {
              var d = Math.floor(s / (24 * 60 * 60));
              s -= d * (24 * 60 * 60);
              var h = Math.floor(s / (60 * 60));
              s -= h * (60 * 60);
              var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
              s -= m * 60;
              s = Math.floor(s);

              var time = "";
              if (!hideDays) {
                time += d > 0 ? d + " day" + (d > 1 ? "s" : "") + ", " : "";
              }
              time += _lpad(h.toString(), '0', 2) + ":" + _lpad(m.toString(), '0', 2) + (hideSeconds ? "" : (":" + _lpad(s.toString(), '0', 2)));
              return time;
            };

            var _setTime = function(time) {
              var _time = _2time(time, attrs.hidedays != "false", attrs.hideseconds != "false");
              ele.html(_time);
            };

            scope.$watch("time", function() {
              _setTime(scope.time);
            }, true);
          }
        };
      }
      ]
    )
  ;
})();
```

It works ok, if I have something like:

```
<span number-to-time time="time"></span>
```

where

```
$scope.time = 1234;
```

It turns that number into readable time format. However, in iOS it does not updates the html.

I have it in a player, and if I log the `html()` content of `ele`, it says it has the correct time, but in the page I still see 00:00:00, and the time does not updates correctly. What am I doing wrong?

**FIXING**

Instead of using .html use .text:

```
ele.text(_time);
```

Comment: Something else I notice is if I turn the video into full screen, then go out of full screen, the text there is updated, but it does not update anymore. I have to do the same, to see the time updated...

Comment: how are you setting `$scope.time` variable in your controller?

Comment: with a timer. But that is not the problem. I just figured it out... after 4 hours searching a friend give me the clue "it was not rendering that part of the page again"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your page is not being rendered. Instead of using html, use text.

```
 var _setTime = function(time) {
   var _time = _2time(time, attrs.hidedays != "false", attrs.hideseconds != "false");
   ele.text(_time);
 };
```

You can find more information here: http://bit.ly/1E4cMxG